# How to deal with ageism as a graduate student?

Tags: age

I have lurked on this site for some time and I have appreciated the intelligent, well-written answers to myriad questions.

My inquiry is the following: I have faced age discrimination in the program I am attending.  This has ranged from consistent age-related comments to rejection of research grants and programs based on age (statement that I am "over-qualified" and "too experienced").  I am in my 30s.  Most of the students are in their 20s.

Should I quit the program?  I am especially interested in the experiences and opinions of older students who have faced similar issues.

Please note that in order to improve the quality of my question I will update it with any and all needed points of clarification.

Comment: In your research proposals, did you mention your age?

Comment: If you are in the U.S.: your university should have a civil rights policy, and it should indicate whom to contact with any age discrimination concerns.  If you have trouble finding this information, try contacting the Title IX coordinator, and asking him or her whom you should contact about age discrimination.  (You could also try a department administrator, but that might or might not be helpful, and if it isn't, it might be a frustration experience.)

Comment: Hi Joel--they ask for birthdates on everything.  You kind of have to list age in that sense.

Comment: @ aparente01 -- In the US universities are notorious for hiding stuff like this while claiming to have policies of non-discrimination.  I might contact an outside attorney.

Comment: What's your field? I know many PhD students in late 20's-early 30's that did not have such issues (in Engineering, top 50 schools).

Comment: @ The Fire Guy -- My area is mathematics.

Comment: What kinds of age related comments do you receive? Certainly your age should not affect any academic evaluations, but socially the unfortunate truth is that if you're different you'll stand out. All you can really do is ignore/deflect the comment or address it head on.

Comment: @Rubik I'm sorry to hear that! It looks like you are in a toxic dept! Can you move to a different school? Can you talk to an academic advisor? I wish I can be of any help!

Comment: @lighthousekeeper There is no quantification in Rubik's question.  We can't tell how many age-related comments have been made, nor how many grant proposals were rejected, nor over what period of time.  Rubik is actually quite young, and is possibly being over-sensitive.